# Strange desktop environment (GNOME) behaviour

Tags: gnome, windows

Why ubuntu 18.04 GNOME behaves strange when requested new apps(windows) to be run? I can explain meaning with help of several examples:

### 1. Usage of Chrome's function "Show in folder" for downloaded files.

- Windows: Explorer opens folder with downloaded files and this window become active on top of GUI.
- Ubuntu: Application "Files" opens folder, but keeps window minimized.

### 2. Starting another application "in background". (When some application starts slow.)

I clicking on application icon and immediatly switching to another running application and typing text there (for example).

When recently opened application would finaly started

- Windows: then window would be minimized.
- Ubuntu: then window become active on top of GUI and interrupts me.

Comment: This behavior not only in Gnome. I use Budgie and the same behavior is present here also.